# Как создать Docker-Compose проект в Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: asp.net-core, docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, rider

У меня есть Asp.Net Core проект в Jetbrains Rider.

Как создать Docker-Compose проект в Jetbrains Rider?

Comment: Как создать Docker-Compose проект в Jetbrains Rider? У меня нету шаблона этого проекта и не смог найти (

Comment: Вы вообще вопрос сами править можете.

Comment: @Suvitruf нет, только комментарии

Comment: гораздо быстрее и эффективнее писать по таким вопросам [сюда](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/rider)